# Electric Flux through a part of plane $x+y+z=a$ via symmetry arguments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

> [image]

> In the given figure, a charge q is placed at $\left(0,\dfrac{a}{\sqrt2},0\right)$. Find flux through the shown surface and represent it as $\dfrac{nq}{6m\epsilon_0}$. Find $m+n$.

> Given ans:7

#### My attempt:

Enclose the charge through four other such triangles in each of the upper octants and a square of side $\sqrt2a$ in the XY plane. Then, the charge is placed at a distance equal to half of the square’s side. It is well known that flux in such a case through the square is $\dfrac{q}{6\epsilon_0}$.

The rest of the flux is distributed equally into each of the four triangular parts of the pyramid. Thus the flux Through each triangular face should be $\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{5q}{6\epsilon_0}=\dfrac{5q}{24\epsilon_0}$. But this gives me $m+n=9$. What did I do wrong?

I don’t have any background in multivariable calculus, but any solutions involving surface integral of $\vec E\cdot \vec{dS}$ are also welcome. I’d just like to confirm the answer.

Comment: I tried it myself and get the same answer as yours, 9. Though I realized I actually used exactly the same method as yours.